# CentOS 4.7 final not seeing my eth0 card

Tags: networking

I have installed cacti on an HP machine, the OS running is CentOS 4.7 final and i don't seem to figure out how the OS can see the card (eth0). I am not an a vivid linux user, so detailed steps would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it show with `ifconfig -a` ? (enter in terminal)

Comment: No it dosen't show

Comment: try `lspci -v` then (look for ethernet, or pipe to grep `lspci -v | grep -A10 net` shows 10 lines after each occurence of _net_). Maybe the corresponding module for your card has not been loaded.